# Why does printing to stdout cause `malloc(): corrupted top size`, but printing to stderr works just fine?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, stdout, stderr

I have the following functions to set up a struct and to dump some data from the struct:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "image.h"

// typedef from image.h included above, copied here for SO
typedef struct image {
    int width;
    int height;
    char *data;
} image;

image *image_new(int width, int height) {
    image *i = malloc(sizeof(image));
    i->width = width;
    i->height = height;
    // allocate space for each row
    i->data = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * height * width * 3);
    return i;
}

void image_dump_data(image *i) {
    for (int x = 0; x < i->width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < i->height; y++) {
            // write pixel color to file
            unsigned char r = i->data[(y * i->width) + (x * 3) + 0];
            unsigned char g = i->data[(y * i->width) + (x * 3) + 1];
            unsigned char b = i->data[(y * i->width) + (x * 3) + 2];
            printf("%d %d %d ", (int)r, (int)g, (int)b);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

As soon as the first `printf()` call is made, my code fails with the message `malloc(): corrupted top size`. When I change `printf()` to `fprintf(stderr, ...)` I get the intended output. The error persists when I use `fprintf(stdout, ...)`, so something specifically about using `stdout` seems to be causing my code to fail.

I hope to have included all the relevant information here, but if necessary, [here is a link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/nsilvestri/the-raytracers/tree/c/c) with all the files I am using with this project.

Comment: How do you "connect" these two functions you show? How do you call them? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us *in* the question itself (making it self-contained without the need for external links that can change, disappear or have their contents change).

Comment: The only difference between `stdout` and `stderr` with respect to this is that the first is normally buffered the second isn't. So the `stdout` version might exhibit an error that you have somewhere else, because in fact is has to use `malloc` at some place. So don't shoot the messenger, `stdout` versus `stderr` is not your problem, it just makes your problem apparent.

Comment: How are the functions called, what is passed in and how is the latter defined and set/initialised? This is essential to know, what we do not, so we needed to guess, what we won't. So, as it stands the question is somewhat incomplete and with this not answerable. Aside the general statement that most likely, guessing again, the infamous Undefined Behaviour is invoked.

Comment: Why the magic number `3` here `(x * 3)` ?

Comment: What do yo pass in as `height` when calling `image_new(int width, int height)`?

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: which file in the `github` link contains the code that is giving you the problem?

Comment: at the linked `github` code, some of the comments are: `idk what's going on`  which means `I don't know what's going on`.  Didn't you write this code?

Comment: regarding; `printf("P3\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);` What is produced by '\n' varies between OSs. and what is expected in the file is 'LF'  Suggest for each newline use: `fputc(LF);`

Comment: please read [simple ppm format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html#plainppm)  especially the statement: *Each sample in the raster has white space before and after it*  which means this statement: `printf("%d %d %d ", (int)r, (int)g, (int)b);`  is missing the leading space in the format statement

Comment: regarding: `unsigned char r = i->data[(y * i->width) + (x * 3) + 0];
            unsigned char g = i->data[(y * i->width) + (x * 3) + 1];
            unsigned char b = i->data[(y * i->width) + (x * 3) + 2];`  each of the bytes of the pixel has (at least) one space before and after each byte so this will not properly decode that image pixels.  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  Also, this; `i->data = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * height * width * 3);` will not allocate enough space so this will be overrun when the data is set into the image.  Remember each data byte must be ascii characters, and each color of the image can have a value of one byte: '0' to 3 bytes: '2''5''5'

Comment: the calculation should be `(y * i->width + x) * 3 + 0` although that is not the source of the error

Comment: Most likely given the info in the question is that heap corruption is cause elsewhere in the program and it happens to manifest itself at this point

Answer (score 1):

I was accidentally exploiting undefined behavior that happens to work when printing to stderr but not stdout (possibly because of buffered vs. unbuffered output). In a separate file I had a bad malloc to the size of a struct pointer, instead of the struct itself, causing the allocated memory to be too small. This didn't immediately manifest as a problem until later. When debugging with `valgrind` the following lines pointed me directly to the problem:

```
==1417933== Invalid write of size 8
==1417933==    at 0x10A864: scene_new (scene.c:24)
==1417933==    by 0x109267: main (raytracer.c:27)
==1417933==  Address 0x4b8b160 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==1417933==    at 0x483977F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==1417933==    by 0x10A823: scene_new (scene.c:23)
==1417933==    by 0x109267: main (raytracer.c:27)
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing your format to avoid the cast? Not sure if it helps but you could try [printf doc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

```
printf("%hhu %hhu %hhu ", r, g, b);
```

Comment: The casts are okay, worst-case they should only lead to the wrong values being printed (as the byte values are sign-extended to `int`). It should not lead to the problem being asked about, which is because of some undefined behavior, possibly in code not being shown.